# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (), Deploy with github pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deployment, web-deployment, github-pages

I have been working on my portfolio website for a little over a month now and I was ready to deploy. I am using vuejs but I am not sure what is causing the problem. also this is my first time using github pages so I am not sure what is the root cause of this problem. It shows in github that my site is deployed to  https://maxwell-clark.github.io/ but it is returning the following error. "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
I am not sure what exactly is the problem. I have read about adding an 404.html file that is an copy of my index.html file